# ovewrite QueryException erorr text message in laravel

Tags: laravel

I update the namespace App\Exceptions  Handler class by adding this code :

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        // Customize the SQL exception message here
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        
        // Customize the error message as needed
        if (strpos($message, 'foreign key constraint') !== false) {
            $customMessage = 'This action violates a foreign key constraint.';
        } else {
            $customMessage = 'An error occurred while processing your request.';
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => $customMessage], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But when the exception is accrued , it return the original error not the new one ,
it is seems i miss some configuration
I am using laravel9

Comment: Try `stripos` as `strpos` is not case-insensitive.

Comment: it is not enter to handler at all ,

Comment: Provide the fully qualified name of the `QueryException` class. If it is correct, this should work.

Comment: It doesn't enter the `render`, or it doesn't enter the `if`? If it doesn't enter the `render`, then maybe you're looking in the wrong section. If it's not hitting the `if`, then it may not be a type of QueryException. You can always try logging before the if. For instance, I have a logging line that starts off with `"{$e->getMessage()}  of type ".get_class($e)." on line {$e->getLine()} of {$e->getFile()}...` inside of my handler.

Comment: It doesn't enter the render at all , i suppose their is some missing configurations